# WP8 + HTML5: Flickering between page changes

Tags: css, html, windows-phone-8

i'm developing an app for Windows Phone 8 with HTML5, CSS, JS, ...

Looks like the default background color of the browser is always white.

So it flickers every time when i click on a link to another (HTML) page (all my pages have black background).

I know i could just use one page and put all other pages into own divs and switch between them with JS, but i would love to use singles pages instead.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the background-color to black does not work?

I've faced this problem quite often myself, but only on the initial loading of the control. The best solution I found until now is to set a negative margin to the webBrowser control and register to webBrowser_Loaded event and then set the margin correctly. Do this for every navigation and you won't experience the white flashing. 
Unfortunately, only setting the visibility property does not work, because rendering the webBrowser-control also makes it flash white.

If you still experience a slight white flash, you may want to set a small wait of about 50ms.

Comment: Hi Malte, yes the background is set to black in the phone.css. The flashing appears everytime between page switches, not only at start. Do you a framework? Maybe this could help if it uses "page transitions" or something like that...